# Change the width of the title background image

Tags: wordpress, css

This is my website. http://hollywoodpress.biz/its-you-zayn-malik/ I would like to change the width of the title background image. I get images from http://placeimg.com/​ this site and every time I update the page, I get different image. But the image size is set to 1000*400. So the image repeats horizontally. I would like to stretch the image. How can I do that? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this,

```
.gdlr-page-title-wrapper {
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/1000/400/tech/sepia');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

or

```
.gdlr-page-title-wrapper {
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/1000/400/tech/sepia');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```